# Executing JQuery from a MVC4 JavaScript Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using MVC4 and I'm doing a simple post back using the below code. However, out everything I've tried I haven't been able to perform JQuery functions inside the JS function but I haven't been able to use any callback functions inside the JQuery block either. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there another way of doing this i.e. just make the ajax callback in JQuery? I'm trying to call a twitter bootstrap function.

**Edit**: Alert as how I'm using is a Twitter Bootstrapper function
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#alerts

My Callback function

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("PostContact", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddContactSuccess"} )){ //My awesome code}
```

Jquery Script:

```
function AddContactSuccess(msg){
    //Can I do JQuery here?
    $('#closeModal').alert(); //Error: alert is not a function
};

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#contact').click(function () {
        $('#contactModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: is `alert` a method you wrote in your custom jquery plugin  ? or the normal `window.alert` ?

Comment: `.alert()` is not a jQuery function. If you're trying to display a generic browser alert then use the code `alert("your message here");`.

Comment: @Shyju no, it is a Twitter bootstrapper function

Comment: is the function in a script tag?

Comment: @MattBodily the function along with the JQuery is in its own .js file but no script tag

Comment: You need to provide more information. What happens after the post? Do you get a javascript error? Is your post successful? The structure of your code looks fine though

Comment: @JeandrePentz What the post comes back as success and I'm simply returning a string stating if there was an error inserting a record or not

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, I got it solved by using $(function(){/*code here*/});

```
function AddContactSuccess(msg){
    //Can I do JQuery here?
    $(function(){
        $('#closeModal').alert(); //Error: alert is not a function
    });
};

$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#contact').click(function () {
        $('#contactModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**keep ahidden element with id="update-message" ,
add UpdateTargetId as below**

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("PostContact", "Home", new AjaxOptions {
UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
 OnSuccess = "AddContactSuccess"} 
)){ //My awesome code}

function AddContactSuccess(){
var msg=$('#update-message').val();
    //Can I do JQuery here?
    $('#closeModal').alert(); //Error: alert is not a function
};
```